# Android - How to download an image and use it as new resource?

Tags: android, image, resources, download

I want to download image from distant server and use it as resource.
Is it possible ?
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you cannot download it as a resource file..you can download and store images on your SDCard or database and load it from there...

To check how to download images to SDCard refer to this link

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/8685#related

You can later load it from your SDCard like this

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-display-jpg-in-sdcard-on.html

This is how you store and retrieve images from ur DB

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/store-imagesfiles-database

Comment: Ok, thank you. But it does'nt tell me how to get the image file from an URL ?

Comment: You can do a bit of googling to find that out...In case you were not able to find it refer to this link http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/converting-image-url-to-bitmap/

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible ?

You can download an image. It will not be a "resource", though. Resources are packaged inside the APK and cannot be modified or added to at runtime.

Answer (score 8):

That's how I did it:

```
private class ImgDownload extends AsyncTask {
    private String requestUrl;
    private ImageView view;
    private Bitmap pic;

    private ImgDownload(String requestUrl, ImageView view) {
        this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        view.setImageBitmap(pic);
    }
}
```

Comment: The above solution works only for small sized images. If image is bigger, results in OutOfMemory Error. Need to scale down image.

Answer (score 4):

This problem was discussed and solved by Gilles Debunne, an engineer in the Android Group, in the blog post [Multithreading For Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html).

It uses already an `AsyncTask` internally. Since it is made for Android it is able to download an image and set it directly to an `ImageView` with the following two lines of code:

```
ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
imageDownloader.download(url, imageView);
```

The `ImageDownloader` class can be found in the linked [repository](http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/).